# Different Set-Cookie header in fetch response from react-native app in ios and android

Tags: express, react-native, fetch

It's strange, but I don't see some set-cookie headers from my express server in react-native app only on android devices!

I use express on my node.js server

```
const express = require('express');
const csrf = require('csurf');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    name: 'sid',
    secret: CONSTANTS.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const csrfProtection = csrf();
app.use(csrfProtection);

app.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
    response.cookie('csrftoken', request.csrfToken());
    response.status(200).send(...);
});
```

I just set csrftoken cookie and send some response;

On client i just get mail page as first:

```
fetch(URL_INDEX, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    }
}).then((response) => {
    //check response here <--------------------------------
    processCookies(response);
    return response;
})
```

What I see in debugger in fetch answer:

In IOS

```
Headers
  map:Object
    connection:"keep-alive"
    content-length:"11716"
    content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
    date:"Fri, 08 Feb 2019 10:58:25 GMT"
    etag:"W/"2dc4-Ew7HRSMcOHECQlBtXIfAuuPw/Vs""
    set-cookie:"csrftoken=bzKoDm5w-CdiLpGk0NWZ1TxaACRNJoRvVeng; Path=/, sid=s%3AGLvycaobuCL7xyIiNRBCXHSZU3SmHmAJ.vv9dzPurvicFvMb%2FkeB9Lshy6ZAQ0SvsMm8cR2ij9O8; Path=/; HttpOnly"
    x-powered-by:"Express"
```

In Android

```
Headers
  map: Object
    connection:"keep-alive"
    content-length:"11716"
    content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
    date:"Fri, 08 Feb 2019 10:52:52 GMT"
    etag:"W/"2dc4-Ew7HRSMcOHECQlBtXIfAuuPw/Vs""
    set-cookie:"sid=s%3AOgeCB1Xsu8yA0SKiXF5Xgdc5pE-gSjfs.cDNHgzc41X1JmnUKmY6Hn3J2%2BrjxbXpBt7%2FhXwN6HbQ; Path=/; HttpOnly"
    x-powered-by:"Express"
```

As you can see csrftoken cookie exists in response on ios, but we don't see it on android.

Any ideas?

Comment: @josemartindev if you read my question, you understand, i hope :) I wrote exactly what I have and completely defined the problem and where it happened. If I didn't do this, you wold have read why my next response is 403 )))